# New vote rep sticks after deleting post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, deleted-answers, reputation-history

[stackoverflow.com/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) is showing me these records:

```
-- 2019-08-25 rep +10   = 50345     
 3  29749903 (-2)
-- 2019-08-26 rep -2    = 50343
```

The random downvote was received on [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29749903/1188513) (10K+ link), which I visited upon noticing my rep score was no longer a nice little multiple of 5 as it had been for 3 days straight (yay OCD!). Seeing that it was an iffy old answer on an off-topic question asked, answered, and closed aeons ago, I decided to delete the post and expected my rep score to go back to 50,345 - but it remained at 50,343.

The notifications dropdown is no longer showing the -2, but my profile's [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mathieu-guindon?tab=reputation) still does, and there's no corresponding +2 / "Removed". I figured I'd wait until recalc before I ask about it... so here we are.

Obviously I don't really care about that +2/-2, but I believe this is a bug - might be related to the score-freeze on old posts, i.e. somehow the downvote score got "frozen" as if it were cast 6 months ago.

Why would a new downvote "stick" on a deleted old post? I don't recall it working like this; rep score associated with votes older than 6 months is frozen (i.e. deleting the post makes no rep diff), but up until this event I was under the impression that rep score (+/-) associated with recent votes would be adjusted/canceled upon deletion of the post.

Comment: I'd suspect chaching delays.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't think the rep history trace involves caching though. Also, it's been a while already. Caching delays over 24 hours? IDK.

Comment: Also last I remember, the "removed" adjustment was pretty much instant.

Comment: OK, fair point.

Comment: @CrisLuengo lol of course! I felt I needed to ask regardless, since I *thought* I understood how that part of the system worked, and visibly didn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That answer is four years old, which means it is eligible for reputation retention upon deletion since it also has a score of 3. That means *all* of the reputation changes from the answer are permanent in its deleted state, including the downvote that recently came in on it that caused you to re-look at it.

Comment: (This is probably designed this way to avoid vote fraud). In order to be fair in this case, Mathieu would not only gain +2 for removing a post that was downvoted, but then also have to *lose* the +30 from the three upvotes already accrued on the post.

Comment: @TylerH TBH what I expected was the old +30 to stick and the new -2 to go, but eh.